# Differences between OdbcConnection and SqlConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I'm in the process of changing the database access in a website from OdbcConnection to SqlConnection. This works already in some specialized parts, but when I change some of the core functions, I quickly get a "timeout" error everywhere. (I'm using "var" in many places, so making a change to the core affect lots of pages.)

Are there known differences between these 2 ways of accessing the database which might be relevant? (I already checked for default timeouts, pooling, etc. but found nothing important.)

Or known problems when transitioning?

Comment: The managed SqlClient driver should perform better from managed code than unmanaged ODBC drivers. I suggest you add a code snippet of a ODBC and corresponding SqlClient query. My guess is the root cause is inattention to detail, such as parameter data types.

Comment: What needs translating are the parameter names in parameterized queries. Where `OdbcConnection` uses a single `?` for all parameters, `SqlConnection` expects parameter names to begin with an `@` and to be unique (e.g. `@p1`, `@p2`...). And I encountered that setting `DbCommand.CommandTimeout` does not have any effect on an `OdbcCommand`, you need to explicitly use `OdbcCommand.CommanTimeout`. Maybe it's that kind of error that causes your timeouts.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reduce it to a snippet. The website uses the database in lots of locations. Some of them via my own library layer. I don't even know if this is caused by one special page (where I may have made a mistake) or just by the general use of SqlConnection.

Comment: Could you please post the codes you have modified which is related with the timeout? How long you faced the timeout issue. As far as I know,it seems the odbc connection timeout doesn't manage the network connection timeout in case of the database is on an other server.

Answer (score -2):

This is the main difference between ODBC and SQL Connection:

1. ODBC is a middle layer between the application and the database. It helps an

application to access any database or data source.

2. ODBC helps in translating the commands of the client application into queries that

are understood by the accessed database.

3. SQL is a standard language that is used to retrieve data from a database.
4. SQL was initially used in minicomputers and mainframe systems, but now it is

popular amongst distributed database systems.

Read more: Difference Between ODBC and SQL | Difference Between http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-odbc-and-sql-2/#ixzz6D5EuzKbL

Comment: How does this address `when I change some of the core functions, I quickly get a "timeout" error everywhere`? I do understand though, this answer is trying to detail the title `Differences between OdbcConnection and SqlConnection`, but not what the post is actually about to be honest.